# Browser plugin for showing the article's posting/modification date

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser-addons, plugins, timestamp

I wonder if there is any browser plugin(for FF or Chrome) that for a webpage shows the timestamp it was written or updated.
As I read many technical articles, I would find it extremely useful, because it would help me to discard old pages whose content might be deprecated.

Tnx.

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox you can right click on the page, select Page Info and see the Modified date/time. It's probably not very useful for most sites though as these days they are dynamically generated on server via scripting whenever you look at them.

If you want it though you could use [this javascript](http://javascript.about.com/library/bllastmod.htm) to construct a bookmarklet to display the last modified date.